# How to Create Relation in Eloquent Relationships Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have Two Table

1- projects

User with id 5 has created 3 project - which means he will have 3 unique conversation with our different agent

```
----------------------------------------
|id | user_id |  title    | time       |
|1  |    5    |  Example  | 2018-06-30 |
|2  |    5    |  Example  | 2018-06-30 |
|3  |    5    |  Example  | 2018-06-30 |
----------------------------------------
```

2- conversation

```
-------------------------------------------
|id | project_id |  user_one | user_two   |
|1  |    1       |     5     |     3      |
|2  |    2       |     5     |     7      |
|3  |    3       |     5     |     10     |
-------------------------------------------
```

Whenever a project is created, a conversation is created with that project id, Now in Laravel i want to get that project detail using Eloquent Relationships.

User_one is the project creator and user_two is our agent assigned to that product.

This is What I've tried

```
class Chat extends Model {
 public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProjectModel');
    }
 }

class ProjectModel extends Model
{
   public $table = 'projects';
}
```

Here is the controller function

```
public function Progress($id){ // Id passed here is 2, so it should show detail of project number 2

    return \App\Chat::find($id)->project()->get();
}
```

After all this I'm getting an error - Call to a member function project() on null

Comment: So far i found this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships is the best available resource on it.. give it a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this with creating 2 Models `Project` and `Conversation`

**table**

```
conversations(id, project_id, creator, agent)
```

**Project Model**

```
public function conversations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Conversation');
}
```

**Conversation Model**

```
public function project(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'project_id');
} 


public function creatorUser(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'creator');
} 

public function agentUser(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'agent');
}
```

**Fetch Data**

```
public function Progress($id){ // Id passed here is 2, so it should show detail of project number 2
     $chats = Conversation::with('project', 'creatorUser', 'agentUser')->where('project_id', 2)->get();
     foreach($chats as $chat){
        dd($chat->project); //it will always print same project because we have filter the conversation by project_id
        dd($chat->creatorUser);
        dd($chat->agentUser);

     }

}
```

Comment: A project can only have one conversation but multiple messages

Comment: yes, thats why if you check `conversation` model has `belongsTo` relation with project. just try to implement this. I have added fetch `project`, `creator` and `agent` through `Conversation`

Comment: Yeah, I have got the project detail. Now what if i need the agent or creator detail?

Comment: i have updated my answer, try that `dd($chat->agent);` and `dd($chat->creator);` be sure `dd` print and die so next line will be not execute.

Comment: $chat->agent and creator are returning only their id

Comment: ah, wait forget to add eager load

Comment: i have update the relation `agentUser` and `creatorUser`, please change these relation and try

Answer (score 1):

you can create a relation Along with specifying foreign Key and owner key like:

```
class Chat extends Model {
 public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\ProjectModel::class, 'project_id', 'id');
    }
 }
```

and then you will be able to get:

```
\App\Chat::where('id', $id)->first()->project;
```

Comment: received an error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::project()`

Comment: you need to retrive the model first to obtain relation on it else try with().. so it should beb `App\Chat::find(1)->project; or App\Chat::where('id',$id)->first()->project;`

Comment: how about this: `$chat = \App\Chat::where('id', $id)->first(); ` and then `$chat-> project`